# Find String at last position of string case insensitive, append a predefined string if not found

Tags: php, regex

I am working on facebook open graph api where user can post the videos in their timeline.
Now the page where we play the video we call it video play page we generate the meta properties dynamically. The process goes as

- The production team adds video in the database and each video has a property called "title".
- In addition there is a separate db table and we call it meta_seo where for each video SEO related information is added. For example title, description etc.

Now while generating the meta information for the page we first check if there is some information on the meta_seo table and if found we generate the meta tags else retrieve them from the video object which will also contain some information so FB og:title we have some information about the video title.

The posting on FB timeline using open graph api works pretty well.

But there are some changes needed on the title being posted.

The title of the videos can be in this format which is stored in the database.

- video title1
- video title2
- video title - mysite.com
- video title | MySite.com

So when we post a video to FB timeline some of the videos may not have the mysite.com at the very end of the title. But we need that mysite.com to be appended always.

So based on above possibilities I have written a script as

```
$haystack1 = "Title1- Online class - mysite.com";
$haystack2 = "Title2 - Online Class";

$needle = 'mysite.com';

if(strripos($haystack1,$needle) === false){
    echo $haystack1.' | '.'MySite.com';
}else{
    echo $haystack1 ;
}


if(strripos($haystack2,$needle) === false){
    echo $haystack2.' | '.'MySite.com';
}else{
    echo $haystack2 ;
}
```

The above code works pretty well. But my question is, is there a better way to achieve this or I can do it the way it I pointed out above.

I am not tagging this to Facebook, since its nothing to do with Facebook and no issues what so ever posting on FB or graph api / open graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for more flexability:

```
if (preg_match('/\s*(-|\|)?\s*'.str_replace('.', '\.', $needle).'\s*$/i', $haystack1)) {
    // do something if exists
    echo $haystack1;
} else {
    echo $haystack1.' | '.'MySite.com';
}
```

So script will output:

```
video title1             => video title1 | MySite.com
video title2             => video title2 | MySite.com
video title - mysite.com => video title - mysite.com
video title | MySite.com => video title | MySite.com
```

Is it that you need? Or you want to replase **- mysite.com** by **| MySite.com** too?

I recommend to use an array for store haystacks and then use my answer above in foreach.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, my goal is to check if mysite.com exists at the end of the string if it does not exist then add " | MySite.com" at the very end of the original string

Comment: echo $haystack1.' | '.'MySite.com'; will return array | MySite.com, where my string is a simple string, but your matching works. But replace does not, so I would wait for a better answer to accept.

Comment: I made a mistake in my answer, check for update, please.

Comment: Ok, now I understand :)